# read a file to check for number and text and write it to different file in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a script which has an output as follows

```
AS1234
1.2.3.4/24
AS4534
2.3.4.5/24
```

I have been trying to write all the CIDR's to one file and ASN number to another. currently I have been using `grep` to write it, can this be achieved through an `if/else` loop?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could do this within a single `awk` program. Have created 2 `awk` variables named `asnOutputFile` and `cidrOuptutFile` which have output file names respectively, you could change output file names as per your need here.

```
awk -v asnOutputFile="ASN_numbers.txt" -v cidrOuptutFile="cidr_values.txt" '
/^AS[0-9]+/{
  print > (asnOutputFile)
  next
}
/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}\/[0-9]+/{
  print > (cidrOuptutFile)
}
'  Input_file
```

OR looking for specific digits values as per shown Input_file then try:

```
awk -v asnOutputFile="ASN_numbers.txt" -v cidrOuptutFile="cidr_values.txt" '
/^AS[0-9]{4}/{
  print > (asnOutputFile)
  next
}
/^([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}\/[[:digit:]]{2}/{
  print > (cidrOuptutFile)
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Eo 'AS[[:digit:]]{4}' > file1

grep -Eo '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}\/[[:digit:]]{2}' > file2
```

Search for "AS" followed by a digit 4 times and output the found entries to file1

Search for 1 to 3 digits and then a full stop 3 times followed by a digit 1 to 3 times and then a forward slash and a digit 2 times. Output the found entries to file 2.